# check running process

Tags: command-line

I am asked to check and shut down the processes that I am not familiar with.
So when I `ls` under bin folder, I see multiple process `.sh`. But I want to know which process is associated with which tomcat process.

Is there any easy way to find out that?

**Example** `startmyprocess1.sh`, but when I do `ps -ef | grep startmyprocess1` doesn't return the running process.

But actually the running tomcat process name is `myprocess`, so when I do `ps -ef | grep myprocess`, I can see the running process. To know that I have to ask the responsible person.

So, the names are different. If like that, I need to ask him several times. Any better way to figure this out?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are really asking for here.. What do you mean by 'checking'? If you want to `grep` the name of the script use `ps l | grep startmyprocess1`.

Comment: For the process you figured out you can try if `grep myprocess startmyprocess1.sh` gives you some pointers. If the scripts are build by the same person, it is very likely you can find the same line in the other scripts too.

Comment: hi all, for my case, I only know startmyprocess1.sh script. but I don't know that script is running for the process myprocess. How can I know startmyprocess1.sh is running for myprocess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting myprocess from within startmyprocess.sh does *not* name the process after the underlying shell script, that is why your `ps -ef | grep startmyprocess1` does not return a result.

This is also why many processes, especially daemons, write their pid out to file so that you can easily reference it's process. This can be done with:

```
#!/bin/sh
pid=`myprocess`
echo $pid > /tmp/myprocess.pid
```

or you can query `$!` which contains the last pid:

```
#!/bin/sh
myprocess
echo $! > /tmp/myprocess.pid
```

and query/list the process by it's pid:

```
ps --pid $PID
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one..,(not tested)

```
ps -aux | grep "yourprocess"
```

For example,

```
ps -aux | grep "httpd"
```

Comment: On MacOS it's `ps aux | grep "yourprocess"` instead of `ps -aux ...` .

Answer (score 0):

I think software like "top" will done great work.

Type:

```
top
```

or

```
htop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach

```
ps -ef | grep startmyprocess1.sh
```

Fetch the Parent PID for `startmyprocess1.sh`, then use below command to find out the parent process from it's PID.

```
ps -ef | grep *PPID*
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @invert has explained a lot, shell script just executes commands within it. What's that means is, you won't get your shell script name at output of `top` or `htop`, which just prints the /proc/$PID/cmdline of each routine within the shell script.

Besides using `echo $!` after command to get the PID of what you want.
I'd like to use `pgrep` command when I need to(or pkill if you would like to kill it).

> pgrep, pkill - look up or signal processes based on name and other attributes

The pgrep simply grep your arguments via /proc/*/cmdline and output matching PIDs
The pkill is compatiable with kill, so you can easily pkill any routine with the cmdline